# Nested Query/Select for MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to query my MongoDB structure, specifically the `users` table to get a specific field, `address`, but am having difficulty because I'm not sure how to access something a couple levels in `users > emails > address`:

```
{
    "_id": "BkWk7hq4MRyMAyK4mm",
    "createdAt": ISODate("2015-11-15T19:46:41.633Z"),
    "services": {
        "password": {
            "bcrypt": "$2a$10$voVzU3pIVZBd1bfJf1oX4.OMPnzi8zXawYY5REtovPayBJL7dZLWSC"
        },
        "resume": {
            "loginTokens": []
        }
    },
    "emails": [{
        "address": "brutus@example.com",
        "verified": false,
        "provides": "default"
    }],
    "roles": {
        "J8Bhq3uTtdgwZdx3rz": ["guest", "account/profile"]
    }
} {
    "_id": "3qfCgFz9r5wKjnmymQ",
    "createdAt": ISODate("2015-12-15T19:49:05.236Z"),
    "emails": [],
    "roles": {
        "J8aBhq3uTtdgwZx3rz": ["anonymous", "guest"]
    },
    "services": {
        "resume": {
            "loginTokens": [{
                "when": ISODate("2015-12-15T19:49:05.280Z"),
                "hashedToken": "c1ybS3U3+GeC8ZNzGQ3WOctWpudQvv4vND6EzlRygtCQ="
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

I was trying to use the following:

```
db.users.find( { emails: { address : "brutus@example.com" } } )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query nested objects with dot notation.

```
db.users.find( { 'emails.address' : "brutus@example.com" } )
```

Your query is correct but it is querying documents for a complete match. So if your emails field had only address field it would work.

With dot notation you can check just one embedded field for matching.

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/query-documents/).

Comment: Would be nice if you could add an explanation of why this is different to what the OP is trying and why what they are trying does not match so they understand it.